# Problem with Facebook Graph API in Node.js application

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, request

I've created the node.js application which is connected with Facebook Graph API. The problem is that when I am using request to get the data from the URL, sometimes I am not receiving the data but this **error message**:

```
  {
        Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 31.13.81.9:443
        at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
        at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)
        code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
        errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '31.13.81.9',
        port: 443
    }
```

When I paste the URL to the browser I am receiving the data from API without any problem.

The request which gets the Facebook API data

```
request({url:`https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me?fields=posts%7Bcomments%7Blike_count%7D%2Cshares%2Ccreated_time%2Csource%2Clikes.summary(true)%7D%2Cfan_count&period=day&since=${selectedDateFrom}&until=${selectedDateTo}&access_token=${accessToken}`,
       json: true
    }, (err, response, body) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {console.log(body);}
```

I wonder why the problem is happening in my application, and why in the browser everything is fine?

Comment: How often is sometimes? Maybe it would happen in the browser too if you tried it more often.  .... you could try increasing the timeout. For multiple request in a short time you can reduce overhead by keeping the connection alive: `request.get(url, {forever: true})`

Comment: So it's about 7/10 times 
I've tried to increase the timeout and it works but after 4 minutes.

Comment: Maybe some wrong escaping? the request library can help you here: `request({url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me', qs: {fields: 'posts...', period: 'day', since: selectedDateFrom, ...}})`